# Does not stop the current song in broadcastrecevier

Tags: java, android

I trying a music app.
I use MediaPlayer object and
My musics play in Broadcastrecevier.
When I touch any songs in list, Music is playing.
But my stop, reset or pause function not working.

MediaPlayerBroadcast.java

```
public class MediaPlayerBroadcast extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private MediaPlayer mPlayer = new MediaPlayer();

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Bundle get_extras      = intent.getExtras();
        if(get_extras.getString("music_name").equals("stop")) {
                mPlayer.stop();
        }
        else {
            String url      = "http://www.tupbebekailesi.com/musics/" + get_extras.getString("music_name");
            mPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
            try {
                mPlayer.setDataSource(url);
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "You might not set the URI correctly!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } catch (SecurityException e) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "You might not set the URI correctly!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "You might not set the URI correctly!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                mPlayer.prepare();
            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "You might not set the URI correctly!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "You might not set the URI correctly!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            mPlayer.start();
        }
    }

}
```

and MusicActivity.java

```
public class MusicActivity extends Fragment implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {

    private ListView music_list;
    private MusicAdapter musicAdapter;
    private List<String> music_list_name;
    private Button stop_music;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView       = inflater.inflate(R.layout.music_activity,container,false);
        music_list          = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.music_list);
        stop_music          = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.stop);

        music_list_name     = new ArrayList<String>();
        music_list_name.add("deadmau5-Alone-With-You.mp3");
        music_list_name.add("deadmau5-Bad-Selection.mp3");
        music_list_name.add("Deadmau5-Clockwork.mp3");
        music_list_name.add("Deadmau5-Faxing-Berlin.mp3");
        music_list_name.add("Deadmau5-Ghosts-n-Stuff.mp3");

        music_list.setOnItemClickListener(this);

        stop_music.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent start_music  = new Intent("com.olkun.medyasef.merhaba");
                //Here I am stop music.
                start_music.putExtra("music_name","stop");
                getActivity().sendBroadcast(start_music);

            }
        });

        musicAdapter        = new MusicAdapter(getActivity(),music_list_name);
        music_list.setAdapter(musicAdapter);
        return rootView;

    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        String name = music_list_name.get(position);
        Log.d("BASLA",name);

        //here I am start any music.
        Intent start_music  = new Intent("com.olkun.medyasef.merhaba");
        start_music.putExtra("music_name",name);
        getActivity().sendBroadcast(start_music);
    }


    private class MusicAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        private Context mContext;
        private List<String> music_array_list;



        private MusicAdapter(Context mContext, List<String> music_array_list) {
            this.mContext = mContext;
            this.music_array_list = music_array_list;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return music_array_list.size();
        }

        @Override
        public String getItem(int position) {
            return music_array_list.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertview, ViewGroup parent) {
            ViewHolder holder           = null;
            String music_list           = getItem(position);

            if(convertview == null){
                convertview         = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.music_activity_area,parent,false);
                holder              = new ViewHolder();
                holder.music_name   = (TextView) convertview.findViewById(R.id.music_name);
                convertview.setTag(holder);
            }
            else {
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertview.getTag();
            }
            holder.music_name.setText(music_list);

            return convertview;
        }
    }

    /*private view holder class*/
    private class ViewHolder {
        TextView music_name;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because everytime you press these buttons (play, stop) a new instance of `BrodcastReceiver` is created (for every new incomming broadcast). So once you've started playing in the first instance of the `MediaPlayer` you can't stop it in another instance of it.
Besides instationating `MediaPlayer` (and using it) inside `BroadcastReceiver` is a bad idea.

Comment: First thanx. if broadcastRecevier a bad idea so what should I use ? Service or other ?

Comment: Yes, `Service` is the best option here. You can still use Broadcasts in order to communicate with your service (it's better to use LocalBroadcasts though). You don't need to bind to your Service if you don't want to.

Answer (score 0):

When you play music on touch you send put extra value to broadcast. when you trying to stop or pause you send another put extra ,but with different values and check in broadcast receiver if stop value exist then stop your music player.